# External hardisks not showing on Ubuntu server

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, hard-drive, raid

I need to access my external hard drives (HP MSA 1040) but i cannot do so, which makes it hard for me to mount them and use them. 
So once i run the command `sudo fdisk -l`. Those disks are not shown. 
What I have done so far:

**Make sure the disks are connected**:
I run this command `cat /proc/scsi/scsi` and get the output below:

```
Attached devices:

Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00

  Vendor: HP       Model: P840             Rev: 3.00
  Type:   RAID                             ANSI  SCSI revision: 05

Host: scsi0 Channel: 01 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: HP       Model: LOGICAL VOLUME   Rev: 3.00
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 05

Host: scsi0 Channel: 01 Id: 00 Lun: 01

  Vendor: HP       Model: LOGICAL VOLUME   Rev: 3.00
  Type:   Direct-Access
```

**I make sure the NIC cards have activity**:
I run this command: `cat /proc/net/dev` and get the output:

```
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed

 eno50:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0  1073628    3152    0    0    0     0       0          0

 eno49:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0  1089630    3201    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

Both the network interfaces have connectivity and bytes are being transmitted.

Any help is appreciated. I dont know what I am missing here which is making it difficult for me to use my disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look for the drives in `/dev/` folder. There should be in kind of `sda` or similar. Then you can try to mount them to an empty folder. If the drives have NTFS or exFAT filesystem you may need to install packages that support these filesystems.